# How to recieve messages for offline clients using QoS MQTT in eclipse-mosquitto?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

My mosquitto.conf is (This is the entire conf file since everything else is just commented out)

```
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
log_type all
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format [%H:%M:%S]
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
listener 1883
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

Then i run

`docker exec -it  ecs-Eclipse_mosquitto_MQTT-11-Eclipse-mosquitto-MQTT-eafxxxxxxx mosquitto_pub -t presence -m hellothere -q qos=2`

(**NOTE** I dont have any active subscribers yet online)

Navigated to `/mosquitto/data` and there was indeed a file called `mosquitto.db`

So i could deduce that my message `hellothere` is stored in `mosquitto.db`

Then i ran the command

`docker exec -it  ecs-Eclipse_mosquitto_MQTT-11-Eclipse-mosquitto-MQTT-eafxxxxxxx mosquitto_sub -t presence -q qos=2`

**What i expect**

For the MQTT broker to send the stored message since subscriber is now online

**What actually happens**

indefinite waiting for the message

Maybe i am missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the relevant bit of the [mqtt spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718104) is:

> When a Server takes ownership of an incoming Application Message it
>   MUST add it to the Session state of those clients that have matching
>   Subscriptions.

In your case when the message is published there are no clients with matching subscriptions (because you have not run `mosquitto_sub` at that point) so it does nothing further.

If you want messages to be stored for a client you must first connect, as that client, and subscribe to the relevant topic (with QOS>0 and CleanSession=0). After doing that any messages received whilst the client is offline will be stored and delivered when it reconnects (as long as CleanSession=0).

Note: To do the above with `mosquitto_sub` you will need to use the `--id` parameter to set the client id (messages will only be queued for the specific clients that have subscribed to the relevant topics). You will also need the `-c` flag to disable the 'clean session' flag.

So the steps will be as follows (I have removed the extra docker bits - you can add these back in):

`mosquitto_sub -c --id subscriber1 -t presence -q 2`

This will subscribe and then wait for any messages; you can safely close it (it's the subscription bit that needs to happen). Next publish your messgae:

`mosquitto_pub -t presence -m hellothere -q 2`

Now you can start `mosquitto_sub` again to retrieve the stored messages:

`mosquitto_sub -c --id subscriber1 -t presence -q 2`

Warning: When you subscribe like this the broker will store any messages received whilst you are offline. This can become an issue if you are testing a broker that processes a lot of messages (because storing all of the messages takes space). Probably not an issue here as you are only testing but something to bear in mind... Running `mosquitto_sub` without the `-c` will clear any subscriptions - there are also options in the mosquitto config that allow you to limit the number of messages held and how long they are held.

Comment: so would i run something like `mosquitto_sub --id 1 -t presence -c clean session=0 ? im not sure how would i disable clean session using -c and adding `clean session false` in my mosquitto.conf results in my container crashing

Comment: The cleanSession flag is a property of the client, not the broker

Comment: It's a flag so just ```-c``` - see the [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) page for full details. I'll add the commands to my answer.

Comment: Sorry - I had not noticed that you also had an error in the way you were setting the QOS levels. The updated commands have been tested and work as expected.

Comment: Sure i will try immediately and accept your answer as soon as i get the result and please dont apologize :)

Answer (score 2):

MQTT doesn't work that way.

Messages are only queued for clients that have previously been connected, it is a pub/sub system not a message queuing system.

A client needs to have been connected in the past and subscribed to the topic the message in question. It then needs to reconnect after the message has been published with the cleanSession flag set to false and using the same client id.

You can read more about this on the HiveMQ blog [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-7-persistent-session-queuing-messages/)

Comment: Sure... so i should first `sub` to the topic disconnect and then `pub` and then when i `sub` again should i expect my message to be recieved ?

Comment: No, there is more to it than that, read the blog post I linked to.

Comment: It says i need to set clean session as false for my client.. how do i do that exactly.. again i really appreciate your help :)